# Getting error "self constructor arguments cannot reference unconstructed this" only if class is same name as class file

Tags: eclipse, scala

In a nutshell, if I define a constructor in a class thats named after the same name as the file itself, it returns the following area.

Some example code. Take the filename as ParseWebsiteData.scala for both.

This returns an error.

```
class ParseWebsiteData(url:String) {

}
```

This however, works fine.

```
class Foo(url:String) {

}
```

The only thing that I'm seeing as the issue are parser bugs from 2013, but this is the latest version of Eclipses's Scala IDE setup so I'm strongly thinking this is not the case, but turns out I'm wrong. Oops :(

As it's still an issue, what are the way(s) to avoid this occurring as I code in the future?

Comment: Well I guess you're referring to this ticket https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1002005-trivial-class-rename-fails-and-presentation-compiler-reports-errors#/activity/ticket. Regardless of how old it is, it is still open, so no wonder that you can have the same  error.

Comment: Similar thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543908/scala-error-when-defining-class/40977434

Comment: I got this error when I accidentally had two class with the same name in the same package.

Answer (score 5):

Well, can't tell the root cause but I was getting the same error in Scala Eclipse editor and I just did "project->clean" and it was gone!