# Scala error when defining class

Tags: scala

I am following the Scala course from Coursera and I have implemented the follwong class:

```
 class Rational(x: Int, y: Int) {

  def numer = x;
  def denom = y;

  def add(that: Rational) = 
    new Rational(
        numer * that.denom + that.numer * denom,
        denom * that.denom)

  override def toString = numer + "/" + denom;

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val x = new Rational(1, 2);
    x.numer;
    x.denom;
  }

}
```

However, I get many compilation errors.
The first of them appears on the first line:

```
Multiple markers at this line:

self constructor arguments cannot reference unconstructed this
constructor Rational#97120 is defined twice conflicting symbols both originated in file '/Users/octavian/workspace/lecture2/src/ex3.sc'
x is already defined as value x#97118
y is already defined as value y#97119
```

The file containing the code is called

```
Rational.scala
```

Why does this error appear?

Comment: The main method needs to be in the companion object to work. Also, are you using worksheets? The code works fine when pasting it into the REPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main` method has to live in the companion `object`

```
class Rational(x: Int, y: Int) {

  def numer = x;
  def denom = y;

  def add(that: Rational) =
    new Rational(
      numer * that.denom + that.numer * denom,
      denom * that.denom)

  override def toString = numer + "/" + denom;
}

object Rational {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val x = new Rational(1, 2);
    x.numer;
    x.denom;
  }
}
```

I also changed the main method signature, as it prevents errors to specify an explicit return type and to use "=". As a rule of thumb: **Never omit the "=" sign**.

```
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
```

instead of

```
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
```

Comment: you can also omit all the `;`, they are mosly not needed/wanted in scala code.

Comment: Why do I need to place the `main` method outside the class?

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the error message `self constructor arguments cannot reference unconstructed this` as soon as I define a class inside an eclipse scala-ide worksheet (.sc File), and give the same class name to it (by accident), as I named a class definition outside the worksheet. Removing the duplicate class name let's the error disappear.